# Html não reconhece caracteres especiais. O que fazer?

Tags: html, css, script

Boa tarde, preciso de ajuda, estou fazendo um jogo com base na programação de um vídeo, e quando eu tento colocar o sinal de menor ou igual (≤) na pasta script.js, o visualcode diz que o caractere é inválido

[Programação com erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99X0j.jpg)

O que faço?

Já tentei procurar por caracteres especiais do HTML, copiei e colei na script.js e mesmo assim não deu certo.

Comment: Ocorre que `≤` não é válido mesmo, o correto seria `arbustoPosition <= 170`. Provavelmente no vídeo que assistiu a pessoa infelizmente está usando alguma firula, como fontes que agrupam caracteres (gosto pessoal é livre, mas parece falta de noção a pessoa usar pra "ensinar" outros). Não consulte vídeos aleatórios na internet, estude por uma documentação confiável, preferencialmente oficial. De qualquer maneira, nenhuma postagem pode depender de links externos (e corre risco de sinalização de spam). Sempre forneça um [mcve] do problema diretamente na pergunta. A [help] tem mais detalhes.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Se o que você está tentando colocar é o operador de verificação (menor ou igual)
que está no if (pipePosition), o operador deve ficar assim para que funcione:

```
if (pipePosition <= 120){
   // seu conteudo aqui
}
```

Repare que no vídeo o (Manual do dev) está usando algum tipo de extensão/plugin no visual studio code que muda o design dos operadores.

Comment: Olá Agnaldo, é legal sua presteza em ajudar, mas nesses casos é recomendado que como já tem pontos suficientes, poste dicas no espaço de comentários. Como resposta não fica bom, pois está tratando de algo que sequer compõe uma pergunta dentro do [objetivo do site](/help), até por depende de link externo (agora removido), ai a resposta nasce "contaminada'' já (e acaba não tendo uma boa recepção). Sobre o `<=`, de fato tem razão, o comparador era a intenção original do código pelo print do autor. Praticamente certo que foi usada alguma fonte com _ligatures_.